# Why do read() and cin.get() affect the output buffer differently?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, terminal

I am trying to write a simple text editor in c++ for Linux. This requires a while loop that reads characters from the terminal, and, so far, I simply display their ASCII values. The problem is that using different input functions results in different outputs.

If i use `read()` to get the characters from the terminal, I have to manually flush the buffer after every `cout` to get output after every key press, something like:

```
char c = '0';
while ((read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1) && c != 'q') {
  cout << std::hex << (int)c<<std::flush;
}
```

If I do not do this, I get output only after the while loop ends, i.e. if I press `q` .

On the other hand, if i use `cin.get()`, then I do not run into any issues. I can simply do

```
char c = '0';
while (cin.get(c) && c != 'q') {
  cout << std::hex << (int)c;
}
```

For context and since I don't know what kind of issue this is, these are some details of my system:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x 
Host: Blade 14 - RZ09-0370 1.04 
Kernel: 6.1.0-17-amd64
Shell: zsh 5.9 
DE: GNOME 43.9
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the C++ iostreams are synchronized with each other.  the C versions are not.

Comment: See also [`basic_ios::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie). `std::cin` and `std::cout` are tied by default.

Comment: The `read` method is overkill for one character.  The primary usage for `read` is to read blocks from an input stream (like 1024 bytes) *without any translations*.

Comment: Modern editors are event driven.  They either use drivers from the operating system to send messages when keys are pressed or the mouse is moved (or a button pressed).  You may want to switch your design.  For example, you may miss a mouse click while waiting for a character from the keyboard.  You may want to use a different input system that doesn't buffer the input.  For example, `cin` waits for the newline before returning a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `cin.get` is synchronized with stdout because there's explicit code for that in the std::stream library (see `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::tie`).

If instead you read directly from `stdin` file descriptor you're bypassing the standard library streams completely, and the output is not flushed before the input because the library doesn't know you're asking for an input.

PS: If you're writing an editor running in a terminal in linux probably you should use `ncurses` library that takes care of a lot of these details and can also handle all key combos and specials (like arrows, function keys, shift, ctrl and the like).